# EKEventStore : Event is not adding in Device Calendar from Start Date only

Tags: ios, objective-c, nscalendar, ekevent, ekeventstore

My String Date is 08-17-2016 10:30. I am converting it to date by this code

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"MM-dd-yyyy HH:mm"];    
NSDate *dateFromString= [dateFormatter dateFromString:eventDate];
NSLog(@"Date :%@",dateFromString);
```

I am getting nslog as **2016-08-17 05:00:00 +0000**. but my time is 10:30.
I dont want to give **end date** because i want it to be there till user delete it.

```
- (void)addEventinCalendar:(NSString *)eventTitle andEventDate:(NSString  *)eventDate
{

NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"MM-dd-yyyy HH:mm"];

NSDate *dateFromString;
dateFromString = [dateFormatter dateFromString:eventDate];
NSLog(@"Date :%@",dateFromString);
//Date :2016-08-17 05:00:00 +0000

EKEventStore *eventStore = [[EKEventStore alloc] init];    
EKEvent *event = [EKEvent eventWithEventStore:eventStore];

event.title = eventTitle;    
event.startDate = dateFromString;         
[event setCalendar:[eventStore defaultCalendarForNewEvents]];    
NSError *err;
[eventStore saveEvent:event span:EKSpanThisEvent error:&err];

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> actually your Date is GMT format,  the time is -5.30 hrs so we need to add the local timeZone and check

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm"]; // set date format as per your String
NSDate *dateFromString= [dateFormatter dateFromString:@"2016-08-17 10:30"];
NSTimeInterval timeZoneSeconds = [[NSTimeZone localTimeZone] secondsFromGMT];
NSDate *dateInLocalTimezone = [dateFromString dateByAddingTimeInterval:timeZoneSeconds];
NSLog(@"Date :%@",dateInLocalTimezone);
```

output

[image]

**updated answer**

try this

```
 EKEventStore *store = [[EKEventStore alloc] init];
[store requestAccessToEntityType:EKEntityTypeEvent completion:^(BOOL granted, NSError *error) {
  if (!granted) return;
  EKEvent *event = [EKEvent eventWithEventStore:store];
  event.title = @"Imran Verified";
  event.startDate = [NSDate date]; // today
  event.endDate = [event.startDate dateByAddingTimeInterval:60*60];  // Duration 1 hr
  [event setCalendar:[store defaultCalendarForNewEvents]];
  NSError *err = nil;
  [store saveEvent:event span:EKSpanThisEvent commit:YES error:&err];
  NSString *savedEventId = event.eventIdentifier;  // Store this so you can access this event later
}];
```

Comment: i m getting date but it s not adding in calendar

Comment: @Imran - happy bro , ok in here try once static data its posted or not, if posted we check with date , ok can you update the question

Comment: @Imran - it means your date issues is solved correct

Comment: i check with static date it is not adding

Comment: @Imran - check the up[dated answer , in here where is your **event.endDate**

Comment: i dont want to add endDate for event

Comment: see this for help http://samwize.com/2014/07/09/how-to-add-edit-and-remove-ios-calendar-events/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/121123/discussion-between-imran-and-anbu-karthik).

Comment: @Imran - event end date is must one with out this we cant sve the events in calendar bro

Comment: @Imran - does not a mean buddy I searched more than half an hour but I found the solution with out end date it wont visible